# Is it possible to keep packages between boots on a Live USB?

Tags: dual-boot, package-management, live-usb

I have a USB with a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 ISO, and when I boot it I can install and use packages as I can on my regular Ubuntu setup. When I restart the system, and boot back into that USB, all the packages I'd installed are gone, and all other changes have vanished too (changing the keyboard layout, etc.).

Why does this happen, and is there a way to stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Popular distributions have a special thing, called Persistence, it's exactly what you are looking for.

Have a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

And to answer your question, live USB simply boots an image, nothing is actually changed inside that image (imagine inserting a CD to boot, it's the same).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the persistence feature actually keeps installed packages. If it does not, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to put all your customization commands in a script that you save in the persistence partition, and run it when you first boot.